# How to create a sum if multiple criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, dplyr

I have to create a "sum if" by column with multiple criteria.

I've tried this:

```
b <- DB.all %>% group_by(Family) %>% summarise(x)
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do it?

Comment: It's not easy to understand what you want to do, could you provide an example? You should read this:[How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: do you possibly want `DB.all %>% group_by(Family) %>% summarise_all(sum)` ... ?

Comment: If python helps, knock.

Comment: If you want to take a sum, then you need to use the `sum` function somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
b <- DB.all %>% group_by(Family) %>% summarise(sum(x))
```